# Which weapons can be socketed with a Gem of Ease for powerleveling?

Tags: diablo-iii

In anticipation of Necromancer coming pretty soon to live. I was wondering which weapons that isn't class specific that you can use with gem of easing to powerlevel from level 1 up to 70 level quickly.

Edit: I don't know why whoever edited my title implied that I am asking for which weapons can be socketed with that gem. I am asking which unique affix weapons (Solanium allow you to use critical strike to create health globe on demand for instance) would work best for int/dext/str classes.

I am planning to solo-rift on the highest difficult I can alone. I may find someone to help me powerlevel. We will see.

Important Notice: I am not asking about contents that isn't out yet. But rather weapons that are released as of 2.5.0 patch version aka Armory/craft mat storage patch.

Comment: If you're not 100% set on soloing: cube Custerian's, save a puzzle ring and have someone run you through a 4 person t6 vault with max gold find and +% exp gear.

Comment: I do have custerian already cubed. But finding a puzzle ring on the other hand entirely RNG-dependable. Not likely but do-able. But the primarily reason why i am not too keen to group up for leveling is that their free time may not match your. Among other reasons. Right now I am looking maybe crafting a hellfire ring (int of course). Save enough mat for a few hellfire amulets (better to wait for necromancer to get the right class passives). On top of crafting/find a nice weapon to level up a new level 1.

Comment: Remember you can use the gem of ease cube recipe to make any item require level 1.  So depending on how invested you are you can have a full generic set with cains, leroic helm, etc.  For super fast leveling, clearly the best option is a full level 1 Legacy of Nightmares setup with ancient items.

Comment: @Vyndicu I edited your question because of this line "I was wondering which weapons that isn't class specific that you can use with gem of easing to powerlevel from level 1 up to 70 level" Which struck me as the gist of the question. Glad you've clarified it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two other answers have not been updated to list weapons with utility effects for leveling. So I took upon myself to go ahead and list a few myself.

I am listing 2-hand weapons because they hit harder and at level 1 you don't need offhand stuff just yet. I am listing anything that has bonus experience guaranteed rolls and/or anything that comes with useful legendary affixes. I am excluding weapons that may roll without one of the three primary stat (int, dex, and str).

```
The Executioner - guaranteed bonus experience 
Burst of Wrath - chance    to restore 20% primary resource 
Wrath of the Bone King - guaranteed cold skill damage 
The Furnace - xx% bonus vs elites is a must 
Sledge of Athskeleng - guaranteed movement speed + x% damage 
Heart Slaughter - guaranteed physical skill damage 
Ahavarion, Spear of Lycander - Chance for a random shrine benefit from killing demon
The Magi - crowd control reduce times on you
The Tormentor - chance to charm
The Zweihander - guaranteed bonus experience
Blackguard - guaranteed less crowd control time on you
Scourge - chance to deal aoe damage as fire
Stalgard's Decimator - chance to deal additional damage
The Sultan of Blinding Sand - chance to blind enemy
Maximus - chance to summon demon pet and guaranteed fire skill damage
Blood Brother - chance to block damage and deal more damage
Corrupted Ashbringer - chance to summon skeletons for pet and aoe damage
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a weapon with a socket in it.

As the [Gem of Ease](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Gem_of_Ease) second bonus at rank 25, sets the level requirement of the weapon it's socketed into to level 1.

I used my rank 25 gem by crafting a level 70 legendary weapon with a socket, and put the gem in that to use on my new character.

If you have a great level 70 legendary which has inspired your new character, you can use a [Ramaladni's Gift](https://www.diablowiki.net/Ramaladni's_Gift) to create a socket in the weapon.

Comment: Answer is still based on an older misunderstood version of the original question.